# Using ISR functions in the Contiki Context

Tags: contiki, isr

I am new to using the Contiki OS and I have a fundamental question.

Can I safely use a low level ISR from within a Contiki Process?

I am doing this as a quick test and it is functioning well.
However, I am concerned that I may be undermining something in the OS that will 
fail at a later time under different conditions.

In the context of a process which is fired periodically based upon an event timer,
I am calling a function which sets up an LED to blink.
The LED blinking function itself is a callback from an ISR fired by a hardware timer on an Atmel SAMD21 MCU.

Can some one please clarify for me what constraints I should be concerned about in this particular case?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can, but you have to understand the context in which each part of the code run in.

A Process has the context of a function, the Contiki's scheduler runs in the `main` body, timers will enqueue process wakes in this scheduler, in fact, think of Contiki Processes as functions called after each other, notice that those `PROCESS_*` macros does in fact call return on the function.

When you are at an interrupt handler or callback, you are in a different context, here you can have race conditions if you share data with processes, the same it would be in a bare-metal firmware where interrupt and `main()` are different contexts.

I strongly recommend you to read about the "protothreads", besides they sound like threads, they are not, they are functions running in the main body. (I believe this link will enlighten you http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/)

On the problem you described, I see nothing wrong.

Contiki itself has some hardware abstractions modules, so you won't have to deal with the platform directly from you application code. I have written big firmwares using Contiki and found these abstractions not very much usable, since it has limited applications. What I did, on this case, was to write my own low level layer to touch the platform, so in the application everything is still platform independent, but, from the OS perspective, I had application code calling platform registers.